# Gmail creating 1pixel line between two images in email

Tags: html, gmail

I've visited frequently for answers to my HTML problems, but this one has me stumped. I have tested the email backwards and forwards in Litmus, and it looks great in everything, but I had one colleague say that a copy that she received in her personal Gmail (using Chrome) always has a 1 pixel line between slices 2 + 3. I've picked apart the HTML character by character and cannot find a difference that would cause this line to only insert itself between these two slices, and none of the others.

A sample is posted below;

```
<tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">
      <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
       <img src="http://Events_02.jpg" width="600" height="155" alt="Text1" style="display:block;" border="0"/>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">
      <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
         <img src="http://Events_03.jpg" width="600" height="146" alt="Text2" style="display:block;" border="0"/>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="center" valign="top">
      <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://Events_04.jpg" width="600" height="177" alt="Text3" style="display:block;"  border="0"/>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you're most likely going to have to share code ...

Answer (score 0):

please have a look on the snippet i have created , this may help you.
Thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  body,table {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
     <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x155" width="600" height="155" alt="Text1" style="display:block;" border="0"/>
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
     <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x155" width="600" height="146" alt="Text2" style="display:block;" border="0"/>
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
     <a href="http://sample.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x155" width="600" height="177" alt="Text3" style="display:block;"  border="0"/>
     </a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```